# Stop excess scrolling after end of content CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, scroll, position

I have a pretty simple site, which has a footer that is stuck to the bottom of the page and a content area that can scroll if the content is too long, and the end of the content will clear the footer like below. If the content fits in the page then no scrollbar is shown.

[image: Here is a page with content that is too long for the page, you can scroll to the bottom of the page and the end of the container will clear the top of the footer]

However, recently some CSS/php change which i can't for the life of me detect, has meant that the page no has this huge area under the bottom of the main content div which the user can scroll down like so.

Normal page view with everything looking as it should.
[image: Normal page view with div located properly just beneath the top of the page]

Here is the view for every page now, a user can scroll way below the end of the main content div to reveal this massive empty area underneath.
[image: Page has now scrolled to far below the content div]

Having had this working nicely a day ago, Im not sure where to look next. I have check all of the css to make sure there are no syntax errors, I have checked all of the wordpress template files to make sure there are no unclosed divs or vice versa.

Does anyone know a starting point to look at to try and fix this? is there a common error for this type of thing? If you need a link to the stylesheet or html just ask (didnt copy as it was too long)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could link to the site so someone could look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are using fade element. Definitely it's causing the issue.

Add this CSS to fix your scrolling problem by hiding it.

```
#fade { display: none; }
```

Comment: ah it was the background per page plugin adding fade to the background image for everypage. thanks Gurpreet!